# Cannot connect to MSSQL due to Login-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error

Tags: java, sql-server

I have an application (web application) written in Java and database on MS SQL. Both, Tomcat (with application) and database server are on my localhost.
I'm trying run an application but in Java logs I have:

> org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Login failed for user 'some-user'.)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'some-user'.

In database logs error looks like:

> Logon   Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 12.
>   Logon   Login failed for user 'some-user'. Reason: Login-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]

When I'm tying login to server via Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio (choosing "SQL Server Authentication") everything is OK.
But with the same credentials my Java application cannot login.

Additional informations:

My connection url is jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1434/some-db

*some-user* has a **public** server role and two database roles membership for some-db (**db_datawriter** and **public**). Default schema for *some-user* is **db_datawriter**.

Additionally *some-user* has *some-db* as a default database.

Comment: which hostname you are using?(localhost,127.0.0.1,etc)

Comment: I'm using 127.0.0.1 in my connection url. I think that connection is OK, but there is some kind of error with database login/user configuration.

Comment: Try out "Localhost" instead. same as first letter uppercase.

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no difference. But ... I tried (for the sake of peace :) this and there is no difference.

Comment: In some cases that worked for me on linux as well as on mac.but not with java and tomcat. I think you need to verify user permissions of the db

Comment: I added (to post body) some information about connection and database login settings.

Comment: @yogs let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1319/discussion-between-michal-mech-and-yogs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you connecting to port 1434? The default port is TCP 1433 for the database instance; UDP 1434 is used for the [browser service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087.aspx), which I suspect is only supported by Microsoft client libraries (I could be wrong, though).

Comment: You hit the bull's-eye. Thanks.