# Unable to connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 using java connection string

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am not able to connect with SQL server 2008 R2 using java. The same code is working with SQL server 2005.

I have tried to find out the port and ip for the sqlserver service and it is giving me

```
ip - 0.0.0.0 and port 1434
```

I tried to use the same connection string that works in SQL Server 2005, but it won't work for me in SQL Server 2008. Here is my connection string:

```
conn=DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1434:DatabaseNameconnect?autoReconnect=true,user, password);
```

This is the Error:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1434;DatabaseName=connect;user=falcon;Password=admin
Could not connect to database
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host  has failed. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.dnb.discovery.connection.ConnectionBean.makeMsSqlConnection(ConnectionBean.java:62)
    at com.dnb.discovery.factory.MssqlDAOFactory.<init>(MssqlDAOFactory.java:18)
    at com.dnb.discovery.dao.mssqldao.MssqlCompanyDAO.<init>(MssqlCompanyDAO.java:8)
    at com.dnb.discovery.relevance.Relevance.modifyRelevanceIndex(Relevance.java:67)
    at com.dnb.discovery.relevance.Relevance.calulateRelevanceScore(Relevance.java:36)
    at com.dnb.discovery.dao.SolrDAO.readDataFromSolr(SolrDAO.java:222)
    at com.dnb.discovery.searchservice.SearchService.buyerTextSearchAnonymous(SearchService.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handleExchange(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any help ?

Comment: What error message or failure condition are you experiencing?

Comment: Which code helps you at SQL Server 2005?

Comment: How about providing an example of how you're trying to connect.

Comment: You didn't give us much info... what's the error, what's the connection string, is DB and app on the same machine etc

Comment: `I am not able to connect with SQL server 2008 R2` which version, btw in the Drivers Folder (installations file or msi) is great manual with code examples for Express or non_free versions too, everything is described on MSDN too

Comment: Never the ip to test can be 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities for your problem:

- Firewall
- No TCP/IP connector
- some services are not running

Try to connect with the SQL-management Studio to you database. If this works, try to connect with SQL-Authentification over TCP/IP.

**update**

Take a look at the Documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms143693(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: I am able to connect with SQL server using management studio.
I tried to find running service using netstat and i found sqlservr.exe is running on 0.0.0.0:65010
I tried to use same ip in connection string but it won't work

Answer (score 0):

One obvious problem is that SQL Server listens on port 1433, not 1434. I've already answered this question [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649518/cannot-connect-to-mssql-due-to-login-based-server-access-validation-failed-with), but I can't be sure if it's an exact match for your problem because you haven't told us what error message you get.

Comment: @user1259350 So the "TCP/IP connection ... has failed" and as I mentioned, you're connecting to the wrong port. Have you read the other question I linked to and have you tried setting the correct port in your connection string?

Comment: @user1259350 Have you enabled TCP/IP on the server? The fact that SSMS can connect doesn't tell you much, because it may be using names pipes or shared memory to connect.